# Please Give a Few Examples of the Schrodinger Equation in Use

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, applied-physics

I know the schrodinger equation has valuable uses in the creation of computers, lasers etc, but how exactly in the construction of these devices is the equation used? Under what circustances does the physicist/engineer say, " I can't construct this until I use schrodinger equation to tell me something." I know the equation gives the probability of finding an quantum particle at a certain loction. How is that used in practice? A few examples would be great. Please be specific. This question is in no why challenging its use. I know it is used and is valuble. My question is how specifically it is used in the creation of a device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly broad question, and I'm sure others will add other things, but I think by far the most direct answer is: Density-functional theory.

This is a way to approximately solve the many-body Schrödinger equation, which is used in materials design processes as a standard in pretty much every industry which manufactures or researches materials. It is used to predict elastic moduli of steel, various properties of finely tuned nanomaterials, and basically anything else in the realm of material science you can think of.

There's actually a matter modelling S.E. which is devoted almost exclusively to density-functional theory.

Comment: Interesting basically the SE is to complicate to use. Thanks for the answer.